# Root test for power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Suppose we have the following series:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{p(p+1)\cdots(p+(n-1))}{n!}z^n
$$
where $p\in \mathbb{N}$ and $z\in \mathbb{C}$. I've applied the ratio test finding an easy limit, but, how can I apply the root test for this series? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to apply the root test, when the ratio test is so easy?

Comment: Stirling formula.

Comment: I think you'd have to establish a generalization of Stirling's formula (to handle the numerator) before the root test became possible. Probably not worth the effort.

Comment: @GregMartin to handle this wouldn't one need to convert the series to a given infinite product and then prove the product converges ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$a_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac {p+k}{n!}=p\frac{ (p+1)_{n-1}}{n!}$$ where appears Pochhammer symbol. Now, considering the asymptotics of the logarithm
$$\log(a_n)=(p-1)\log(n)+\log
   \left(\frac{p}{\Gamma (p+1)}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ Neglecting the constant term
$$\frac 1 n \log(a_n)=(p-1)\frac{\log(n)} n+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\exp\left(\frac 1 n \log(a_n) \right)\sim n^{(p-1)/n}$$